# FactoryGirl and a recursive model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot

I'm having trouble figuring out how to setup a factory for my class with a has_many/belongs_to relationship referencing the parent class.  It is set up as followed.

```
class PrivateMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body, :read_at, :title, :receiver_id, :sender_id, :conversation_id
  belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'Profile', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
  belongs_to :receiver, class_name: 'Profile', foreign_key: 'receiver_id'
  belongs_to :conversation, :class_name => 'PrivateMessage'  # Reference to parent message
  has_many :replies,  :class_name => 'PrivateMessage', :foreign_key => 'conversation_id',
    order: 'created_at DESC'
```

I am a bit at a loss at how to approach this, or if I should even be using a factory in this case.  In my controller, I create a message if the conversation_id is nil normally (using profile.sent_messages.build), otherwise if there are any messages between the sender/receiver I reference the parent message, and use parent_message.replies.build to build it.

I think I need some sort of nested factory with an after_build hook, but I can't quite wrap my head around how to do it.  Something like this?  Where I define private message above.  This is obviously wrong, but am I on the right track?  How can I reference the parent message with the after_build block?

```
factory :private_message do
  sequence(:body) { |n| "This is a body of a message :) #{n}" }
  association :sender
  association :receiver
end  

factory :reply do
  association :private_message
  sequence(:body) { |n| "This is the body of a reply #{n}" }
  association :sender
  association :receiver
  after_build do |private_message|
    private_message.replies << :reply
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question...

Does something like this make sense?

```
factory :private_message do
  sequence(:body) { |n| "This is a body of a message :) #{n}" }
  association :sender
  association :receiver

  factory :reply do
    sequence(:body) { |n| "This is the body of a reply #{n}" }
    association :conversation
  end
end
```

You might make your life easier breaking conversations out into a separate model...

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks.  Took me a minute to realize that I needed to use a let! instead of let to make it work, but that was simple.  Thanks for the help.